# Python PIL Image in Label auto resize

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a widget to hold an image that will automatically resize to fit its container, e.g. if packed directly into a window, then expanding that window will expand the image.

I have some code that is semi functional but I've had to add a couple of constants into one of the routines to prevent the auto resize from re triggering itself (causing it to keep growing in size)

I'm sure that the reason for this is due to the widgets internal padding/border, but even trying to take that into account I get this issue.

I'm using python 3.3.2, and PIL 1.1.7 on 64 bit Windows 7
my code is the following:

```
from tkinter import tix
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def Resize_Image(image, maxsize):
    r1 = image.size[0]/maxsize[0] # width ratio
    r2 = image.size[1]/maxsize[1] # height ratio
    ratio = max(r1, r2)
    newsize = (int(image.size[0]/ratio), int(image.size[1]/ratio)) # keep image aspect ratio
    image = image.resize(newsize, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    return image

class Pict_Frame(tix.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, picture=None, maxupdate=None, **kwargs):
        tix.Label.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self._resize_binding)
        self.maxupdate = maxupdate
        self.update_after_id = None
        self.photo = None
        self.image = None
        if picture:
            self.set_picture(picture)

    def _resize_binding(self, event):
        if self.photo:
            if not self.maxupdate:
                self.load_picture()
            else:
                if not self.update_after_id:
                    self.update_after_id = self.after(int(1000/self.maxupdate), self.load_picture)

    def load_picture(self):
        if self.photo:
            if self.update_after_id:
                self.update_after_id = None
            if (self.winfo_width() > 1) and (self.winfo_height() > 1): # prevent updates before widget gets sized
                self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Resize_Image(self.photo, (
                             self.winfo_width()-int(self.cget("bd"))-1, self.winfo_height()-int(self.cget("bd"))-1))) 
                # here is where I added the constants ^^^
                # but even using cget to get the border size I have had to add to this
                # to prevent the resize loop, and when using other widget styles
                #(raised etc) this problem persists

                self.configure(image=self.image)

    def set_picture(self, filename):
        with open(filename, mode="rb") as file:
            self.photo = Image.open(file)
            self.photo.load() # load image into memory to allow resizing later without file access
        self.load_picture()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Pict_Frame(bg="grey", bd=2, relief="raised",
                      maxupdate=2, # allows problem to be easily seen
                      picture="image.jpg")
    test.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    test.master.mainloop()
```

when I apply other styles, such as a thicker border (10px) this resizing problem occurs showing that the constants don't really solve the problem.
so is there any method to get only the space inside the widget, instead of its requested size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I have now solved this, but it really needs a lot more testing with different parameters to ensure accurate results. The code I have use to test this is as follows:

```
from tkinter import tix
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def Resize_Image(image, maxsize):
    r1 = image.size[0]/maxsize[0] # width ratio
    r2 = image.size[1]/maxsize[1] # height ratio
    ratio = max(r1, r2)
    newsize = (int(image.size[0]/ratio), int(image.size[1]/ratio)) # keep image aspect ratio
    image = image.resize(newsize, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    return image

class Pict_Frame(tix.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, picture=None, maxupdate=None, imagesize=None, **kwargs):
        tix.Label.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self._resize_binding)
        self.maxupdate = maxupdate
        self.imagesize = imagesize
        self.update_after_id = None # used for update rate limiting
        self.photo = None # used to store raw image from file for later use
        self.image = None # used for reference to the resized image
        if imagesize:
            self.photo=Image.new("RGB", (1,1)) # create empty image to insert
            self.image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.photo) # create instance of image for PIL
            self.configure(image=self.image)
            self.configure(width=imagesize[0], height=imagesize[1]) # not label uses pixels for size, set size passed in
        if picture:
            self.set_picture(picture) # we have a picture so load it now

    def _resize_binding(self, event):
        if self.photo: # we have a picture
            if not self.maxupdate: # no rate limiting
                self.load_picture()
            else:
                if not self.update_after_id: # if we're not waiting then queue resize
                    self.update_after_id = self.after(int(1000/self.maxupdate), self.load_picture)

    def load_picture(self):
        if self.photo:
            if self.update_after_id:
                self.update_after_id = None
            if (self.winfo_width() > 1) and (self.winfo_height() > 1): # prevent updates before widget gets sized
                bd = self.cget("bd") # get the border width
                if type(bd) != int: # if there was no border set we get an object back
                    pad = 4 # set this explicitly to avoid problems
                else:
                    pad = int(bd*2) # we have a border both sides, so double the retrieved value
                newsize = (self.winfo_width()-pad, self.winfo_height()-pad)
            elif self.imagesize: # only use the passed in image size if the widget has not rendered
                newsize = self.imagesize
            else:
                return # widget not rendered yet and no size explicitly set, so break until rendered
            self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Resize_Image(self.photo, newsize))
            self.configure(image=self.image)

    def set_picture(self, filename):
        with open(filename, mode="rb") as file:
            self.photo = Image.open(file)
            self.photo.load() # load image into memory to allow resizing later without file access
        self.load_picture()
```

and my test cases were:

```
import os
    path = "E:\imagefolder"
    images = []
    ind = 0
    for item in os.listdir(path): # get a fully qualified list of images
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, item)):
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, item, "thumb.jpg")):
                images.append(os.path.join(path, item, "thumb.jpg"))

    def callback():
        global ind
        ind += 1
        if ind >= len(images):
            ind = 0
        pict.set_picture(images[ind])

    ignore_test_cases = []

    if 1 not in ignore_test_cases:
        print("test case 1: - no border no set size")
        root = tix.Tk()
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).pack()
        pict = Pict_Frame(parent=root, bg="grey",
                          maxupdate=2, # allows problem to be easily seen
                          picture=images[ind])
        pict.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).pack()
        root.mainloop()

    if 2 not in ignore_test_cases:
        print("test case 2: - small border no set size")
        root = tix.Tk()
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).pack()
        pict = Pict_Frame(parent=root, bg="grey", bd=2, relief="raised",
                          maxupdate=2,
                          picture=images[ind])
        pict.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).pack()
        root.mainloop()

    if 3 not in ignore_test_cases:
        print("test case 3: - large border no set size")
        root = tix.Tk()
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).pack()
        pict = Pict_Frame(parent=root, bg="grey", bd=10, relief="raised",
                          maxupdate=2,
                          picture=images[ind])
        pict.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).pack()
        root.mainloop()

    if 4 not in ignore_test_cases:
        print("test case 4: - no border with set size")
        root = tix.Tk()
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).pack()
        pict = Pict_Frame(parent=root, bg="grey",
                          maxupdate=2,
                          imagesize=(256,384),
                          picture=images[ind])
        pict.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).pack()
        root.mainloop()

    if 5 not in ignore_test_cases:
        print("test case 5: - small border with set size")
        root = tix.Tk()
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).pack()
        pict = Pict_Frame(parent=root, bg="grey", bd=2, relief="raised",
                          maxupdate=2,
                          imagesize=(256,384),
                          picture=images[ind])
        pict.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).pack()
        root.mainloop()

    if 6 not in ignore_test_cases:
        print("test case 6: - large border with set size")
        root = tix.Tk()
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).pack()
        pict = Pict_Frame(parent=root, bg="grey", bd=10, relief="raised",
                          maxupdate=2,
                          imagesize=(256,384),
                          picture=images[ind])
        pict.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).pack()
        root.mainloop()

    if 10 not in ignore_test_cases:
        print("test case fullscreen: - small border no set size, in fullscreen window with expansion set up")
        root = tix.Tk()
        root.state("zoomed")
        root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="nesw")
        pict = Pict_Frame(parent=root, bg="grey",# bd=10, relief="raised",
                          maxupdate=2,
                          picture=images[ind])
        pict.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky="nesw")
        tix.Button(root, text="Next Image", command=callback).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky="nesw")
        root.mainloop()

    if 11 not in ignore_test_cases:
        print("test case fullscreen: - small border no set size, in fullscreen window with expansion set up")
        root = tix.Tk()
        root.state("zoomed")
        root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        frame = tix.Frame(root)
        frame.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="nesw")
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        tix.Button(frame, text="Next Image", command=callback).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="nesw")
        pict = Pict_Frame(parent=frame, bg="grey",# bd=10, relief="raised",
                          maxupdate=2,
                          picture=images[ind])
        pict.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="nesw")
        tix.Button(frame, text="Next Image", command=callback).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky="nesw")
        root.mainloop()
```

The only issue I have had with this code is that when I am using the widget in a full-screen application the re-sizing doesn't work as intended, when using the grid method and setting the weight of the right column to 1 (with the pict widget) and the left column (empty) to 1, the right column ends up taking approx 2/3rds the width of the screen.

I suspect this is due to explicitly setting the size of the image, which then makes it wider, meaning the geometry manager wants to make it wider still (ad infinitum) until it reaches some equilibrium. But if anyone can shed any light on this (or even a solution) it would be appreciated.